# 3D object position prediction using Kalman filter, variable time period

Tags: opencv, prediction, kalman-filter

I'm working on advanced vision system which consist of two static cameras (used for obtaining accurate 3d object location) and some targeting device. Object detection and stereovision modules have been already done. Unfortunately, due to the delay of targeting system it is obligatory to develop a proper prediction module.

I did some tests using Kalman filter but it is working not accurate enough.

```
kalman = cv2.KalmanFilter(6,3,0)
...
            kalman.statePre[0,0]  = x
            kalman.statePre[1,0]  = y
            kalman.statePre[2,0]  = z
            kalman.statePre[3,0]  = 0
            kalman.statePre[4,0]  = 0
            kalman.statePre[5,0]  = 0

            kalman.measurementMatrix = np.array([[1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0,0]],np.float32)

            kalman.transitionMatrix = np.array([[1,0,0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0,1,0],0,0,1,0,0,1],[0,0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1]],np.float32)

            kalman.processNoiseCov = np.array([[1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0,0],0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1]],np.float32) * 0.03


            kalman.measurementNoiseCov = np.array([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],0,0,1]],np.float32) * 0.003
```

I noticed that time periods between two frames are different each time (due to the various detection time).

1. How could I use last timestamp diff as an input? (Transition matrices?, controlParam?)
2. I want to determine the prediction time e.g want to predict position of object in 0,5sec or 1,5sec

I could provide example input 3d points.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

### 1. How could I use last timestamp diff as an input? (Transition matrices?, controlParam?)

Step size is controlled through prediction matrix. You also need to adjust process noise covariance matrix to control uncertainty growth.

You are using a constant speed prediction model, so that `p_x(t+dt) = p_x(t) + v_x(t)·dt` will predict position in X with a time step `dt` (and the same for coords. Y and Z). In that case, your prediction matrix should be:

```
kalman.transitionMatrix = np.array([[1,0,0,dt,0,0],[0,1,0,0,dt,0],0,0,1,0,0,dt],[0,0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1]],np.float32)
```

I left the process noise cov. formulation as an exercise. Be careful with squaring or not squaring the `dt` term.

### 2. I want to determine the prediction time e.g want to predict position of object in 0,5sec or 1,5sec

You can follow two different approaches:

1. Use a small fixed dt (e.g. 0.02 sec for 50Hz) and calculate predictions in a loop until you reach your goal (e.g. get a new observation from your cameras).
2. Adjusting prediction and process noise matrices online to the desired dt (0,5 / 1,5 sec in your question) and execute a single prediction step.

If you are asking about how to anticipate the detection time of your cameras, that should be a different question and I am afraid I can't help you :-)